# Removing Gel Pen Ink from a Book Log

Tags: books

I have a book log (with fiil-in-the-blank spaces) that I keep track of what I read in. I try my best to keep it extremely neat, but I put the wrong information on a blank. How can I remove the ink (gel) without damaging the ink printed on the page? (There are lines to indicate where the answer should go.) I am using a Pilot G-2 07 pen.

Comment: I would use correction tape such as [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Correction-Large-Capacity-Correct-Roller-Office/dp/B09Z69TLYF).

Comment: Gel pen ink is very hard to remove and not soluble in common solvents when dried. You might be able to use some kind of abrasive but it is unlikely to give a good finish and will damage other marks on the surface. So, as the previous comment says, you're probably limited to methods that cover the ink. And in future use an ink that is more easily removable.

Answer (score 1):

If [**liquid paper**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_Paper) is not an option, you can try the solution which I used when I was a child in school. Use a classic shaving razor, and carefully scrap away the ink. With enough care and patience, you can get the job done.

WARNING: if the ink penetrated the paper (instead of just sitting as a layer on the top of the paper), then the razor method will most likely end up creating a hole in the paper, before removing the ink.